# where can I download php extension

Tags: php

I am a beginner for php. And now I need to get some php extension as below.

```
[ERROR] bcmath: Extension bcmath does not exist.
[ERROR] bz2: Extension bz2 does not exist.
[ERROR] curl: Extension curl does not exist.
...
```

for java jar, I know we can get it from maven repository or *www.java2s.com *. But how to do about php extension. And I know I can get extension(xx.so) through **phpize** command when we have source code of it. But now I dont have anything. what I should do? just search *bcmath.so* in google? Are there exist some easy way?

Comment: Contact with your domain admin

Comment: least you could do is tell us what OS this php is running under, whether you have proper privileges.

Comment: @YvesLe   my os is ubuntu16.04. and for some extension like `ereg`. I dont know where can i get it. And i try the command `sudo apt-cache search erge` failed to find extension which I need.

Answer (score 0):

PHP extensions are typically installed via whatever package manager your OS uses. For example, on Debian-based Linux distributions, you'd likely use:

```
apt-get install php-bcmath php-bz2 php-curl
```

If you're compiling PHP yourself, you'll need to include those extensions via the configure script before you build:

```
configure --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --with-curl
```